# disable output to log4j.rootLogger

Tags: java, log4j

I am having problem that even though I specify the property `log4j.additivity=false` ,still log messages are getting displayed in both logs (Root log and intended log).
But I want to log only in intended log file how can I achieve it through configuration in properties file.

I am not a log4j expert so any help is appreciated.

my log file looks like this

```
#==============================================
# RIPNET Logger (..//logs everything under the sun)
#==============================================
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, RIPNETappender
log4j.appender.RIPNETappender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RIPNETappender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RIPNETappender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%t:%c] - <%m>%n
log4j.appender.RIPNETappender.File=..//logs//RIPNET.log

#====================================
# WorkOrder Logger
#====================================
log4j.logger.com.reino.ripnet.servlet.alarm=INFO, WorkOrderAppender
log4j.appender.WorkOrderAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.additivity.com.reino.ripnet.servlet.alarm=false
log4j.appender.WorkOrderAppender.File=..//logs//WorkOrder.xml.log
log4j.appender.WorkOrderAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.WorkOrderAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%t:%c] - <%m>%n
```

though i set the value

```
log4j.additivity.com.reino.ripnet.servlet.alarm=false
```

the log messages are still getting logged in root log
i even tried setting

```
log4j.additivity.WorkOrderAppender=false
```

in the code i call the logger by

```
Logger  logger = Logger.getLogger("WorkOrderAppender");
```

i also tried using

```
Logger  logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
```

but still no use

Comment: Config looks good to me, how do you create logger instance in code?

Comment: Try creating `Logger.getLogger("com.reino.ripnet.servlet.alarm");` ?

Comment: i tried with Logger.getLogger("com.reino.ripnet.servlet.alarm"); but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Loggers and appenders. Additivity can be configured on a logger, and the Logger takes the `<severity level>` and an `<appender name>` as argument. Look closely at how I renamed your WorkOrder* names (* = {Appender, Logger}).

Thus, the combination of

```
log4j.logger.WorkOrderLogger=INFO, WorkOrderAppender
log4j.additivity.WorkOrderLogger=false
```

and

```
Logger  logger = Logger.getLogger("WorkOrderLogger");
```

should work.